# Filter sequence to subsequence with elements evenly apart

Tags: algorithm, sequence, generic-programming

I have an input of integers (or floats), eg.

`100, 203, 230, 280, 400, 410, 505, 600`

And I want to filter them to get a subsequence so that the numbers would be almost evenly apart, that is, remove outsiders, in my case, the filtered sequence would be:

```
100, 203, 280, 400, 505, 600
```

Since they all lie about 100 units from each other.

In addition I also know that the average distance of the whole sequence is limited, eg. 
70 < dist < 130.

What algorithm should I use?

Extra: Could the algorithm be improved that it would also work if now and then an element of the sequence would be missing, e.g. 505:

```
100, 203, 230, 280, 400, 410, 600
```

So the result would be either

```
100, 203, 280, 400, 600
```

or something like

`100, 203, 280, 400, 500, 600`

Also: I am working with semi-big data and would prefer prefer a fast solutions (not checking all possible subsequences for example).

Comment: by avgerage distance you mean average of pair-wise adjacent distances ?

Comment: yes, i want a sequence a0, a1, a2,... such that 
lower limit <= |a(i+1) - ai| <= upper limit